# Why is the norm of an ideal contained in that ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K$ is a number field and that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. Now, let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$. I know that $N(I) \in I$, but I want to prove it.

By definition, $N(I)= \#\mathcal{O}_K / K$.

A proof given by our lecturer invokes "a theorem of Lagrange" to note that, for *any* $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ we have that $N(I).x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and so by setting $x=1$ the result follows.

Can someone please flesh this out a little for me.

What is the theorem of Langrange (because I can't see how 'Langrange's Theorem' gives us this result)? And how is it applied?

Thanks.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is the one from group theory. Applied to the finite additive group ${\mathcal O}_K/I$, whose size is $N(I)$, it says the additive order of any element divides the size of the group, so $N(I)x \equiv 0 \bmod I$ for all $x \in {\mathcal O}_K$. Thus $N(I)x \in I$ for all $x$, and for $x = 1$ this says  $N(I) \in I$.

Comment: @KCd Thank you; please consider adding this as an answer so that it can be upvoted and this question can be removed from the unanswered list.